# How to download a file from 3ftp sites

Tags: python

I have a list of ftp sites ( eg:10 ) in text file and i need to download the last created file from ftp sites. Is this possible. This is my code :

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP("xxx.xx.xx.xx1", "USERNAME1", "PASSWORD1")
ftp = FTP("xxx.xx.xx.xx2", "USERNAME2", "PASSWORD2")
ftp = FTP("xxx.xx.xx.xx3", "USERNAME3", "PASSWORD3")
ftp = FTP("xxx.xx.xx.xx4", "USERNAME4", "PASSWORD4")
ftp = FTP("xxx.xx.xx.xx5", "USERNAME5", "PASSWORD5")

ftp.login()
ftp.retrlines("LIST")

ftp.cwd("SmythIN/2014-10-29") --- here  i have a folder created by current  date ...how can i pass current date folder i change directory.
ftp.cwd("subFolder") # or ftp.cwd("folderOne/subFolder")

listing = []
ftp.retrlines("LIST", listing.append)
words = listing[0].split(None, 8)
filename = words[-1].lstrip()

# download the file
local_filename = os.path.join(r"c:\myfolder", filename)
lf = open(local_filename, "wb")
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, lf.write, 8*1024)
lf.close()
```

updated code :

```
ftp.cwd("SmythIN/2014-10-29")- the directory with today date is already created.
```

Comment: How does getting the latest file differ from a server differ from running it on different servers? Or do you ask how to write a `for` loop which would iterate over servers?

Comment: yes Luke if we write this in a loop how can we know which is  file from which server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looping through the servers and pulling the last file within specified directories (if I understand your question correctly) is straight forward.  Remembering what server each file came from should not be problematic either since you can use different local directories on your local machine or edit the filename as the file transfers.  Here is my suggestions (to be modified to your application of course):

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP

# read in text file containing server login information and jam into dictionary
with open('server_file.txt','r') as tmp:
    servers = {}
    for r in tmp.read().split('\n'):
        rs = r.split(',') # split r by comma
        servers[rs[0]] = {'uname':rs[1],'pwd':[rs[2]]}

# if you want to create a new directory to save the file to
heute = dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.today(),'%Y%m%d')
if os.path.isdir('my_dir' + heute)==False:
    os.mkdir('my_dir' + heute)


for s in servers:
    ftp = FTP(s,servers[s]['uname'],servers[s]['pwd'])
    ftp.cwd('desired_subdir')

    # if you want to download the last file I would us nlst
    with open('local_file','wb') as lf:
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR' + ftp.nlst()[-1], lf.write, 8*1024)
```

Comment: can you tell how can we get the desired _subdir as a folder is created with todays date everyday and also need    file datetime created.Thanks once again.

Comment: I updated the post to include directory creation, which I think is what you were wanting.  Naming the file would be similar to naming the directory above.  However, I am unsure of what datetime you want in the filename.  If you want the mod time use os.path.getmtime, creation time would be os.path.getctime, etc.  Just play around with it.

Comment: you got me wrong the directory is already created  how can we pass todays dated direcorty in desired _sub dir and and how can we get the file creation datetime also. sorry for the trouble. Thanks